# Игнорирование текста в определённых тегах

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Доброе время суток.
Есть html текст, так же есть ключевые слова. Производится поиск в тексте на ключевые слова и формируется ссылка. Так как это html текст в нем содержится другие ссылки их нужно игнорировать, возможно совпадение ключевого слова текста в ссылке и это не правильно (на данный момент будет два закрывающих тега а).

```
<div id="text">
  <p>Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в домашних условиях. При создании генератора мы использовали небезизвестный универсальный код речей. Текст генерируется абзацами случайным образом от двух до десяти предложений в абзаце, что позволяет <a href="/test">сделать текст более привлекательным</a> и живым для визуально-слухового восприятия.</p>
</div>
<script>
var str = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;

var ar_pl = ['верстальщик', 'дизайнер', 'вебмастер', 'текст'];

var array = [
    ['дизайнер', '/designer'],
    ['верстальщик', '/coder'],
    ['вебмастер', '/webmaster'],
    ['текст', '/texts'],
];

var regexp, context, array, key;
for (key in array) {

  prg = '(?:^|[^а-яё])('+array[key][0]+'(?:[а-яё]*))';

  regexp = new RegExp(prg, 'gi');

  if (!context) {
    context = str.replace(regexp, ' <a href="'+array[key][1]+'">$1</a>');
  } else {
    context = context.replace(regexp, ' <a href="'+array[key][1]+'">$1</a>');
  }
}

if (context) {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = context;
}
</script>
```

Comment: возьмите фрагмент и querySelectorAll

Comment: не совсем понятно что имеете ввиду.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```js
var str = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;

var ar_pl = ['верстальщик', 'дизайнер', 'вебмастер', 'текст'];

var array = {
    'дизайнер': '/designer',
    'верстальщик': '/coder',
    'вебмастер': '/webmaster',
    'текст': '/texts',
};

var context, array, key;
var keys_rx = Object.keys(array).join("|");
var prg = '(<a(?:\\s+[^>]*)?>[^<]*</a>)|(?:^|[^а-яё])(('+keys_rx+')[а-яё]*)';
var regexp = new RegExp(prg, 'gi');
console.log(regexp)

if (!context) {
  context = str.replace(regexp, function ($0,$1,$2,$3) { return $1 ? $0 : ' <a href="'+array[$3.toLowerCase()]+'">' + $2 + '</a>';});
} else {
  context = context.replace(regexp, function ($0,$1,$2,$3) { return $1 ? $0 : ' <a href="'+array[$3.toLowerCase()]+'">' + $2 + '</a>';});
}
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = context;
```

```html
<div id="text">
  <p>Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в домашних условиях. При создании генератора мы использовали небезизвестный универсальный код речей. Текст генерируется абзацами случайным образом от двух до десяти предложений в абзаце, что позволяет <a href="/test">сделать текст более привлекательным</a> и живым для визуально-слухового восприятия.</p>
</div>
```

Регулярное выражение:

```
/(<a(?:\s+[^>]*)?>[^<]*<\/a>)|(?:^|[^а-яё])((дизайнер|верстальщик|вебмастер|текст)[а-яё]*)/gi
```

См. [пример его работы](https://regex101.com/r/2JbLgM/1/)

- `(<a(?:\s+[^>]*)?>[^<]*<\/a>)` - находит и помещает тег `<a>` и его содержимое в подмаску №1
- `(?:^|[^а-яё])((дизайнер|верстальщик|вебмастер|текст)[а-яё]*)` - находит слово, начинающееся с одного из ключей массива `array`, помещает найденный ключ в подмаску №3, а целое слово в подмаску №2.
- `function ($0,$1,$2,$3) { return $1 ? $0 : ' <a href="'+array[$3.toLowerCase()]+'">' + $2 + '</a>';}` - анонимная функция обратного вызова, которая подставляет обратно значение подмаски №1 (если она найдена) или отформатированную ссылку согласно найденному ключу.